# Perl OLE document visible

Tags: excel, perl, ole, visible

I try to open and modify an Excel document with a Perl script, and I want this document to be still open after. I use the following code :

```
unless (defined $ex) {
$ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub{$_[0]->Quit;})
or die "Cannot start Excel";
}

$ex->{Visible} = 1;
```

The Excel document briefly appears, then vanishes. The work is correctly done, but Excel closes down after. Is there a way to keep Excel open?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your **destructor** construct from the new method:

```
$ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application')
or die "Cannot start Excel";
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this answer. This works perfectly. Problem of people recopying codes that they don't understand...I swear you to try to stop being a script-kiddie.